# SQL Modeling Pyramid or Binary Tree

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a sql server project that have a `pyramid` or `binary tree` concept...

I gonna try to explain using some tables!

The first table is

> TB_USER(ID, ID_FATHER, LEFT/RIGHT TREE POSITION)

User can sell producs! So when they sell they earn points. Then, the second table is

> TB_SELL (ID_USER, ID_PRODUCT, POINT)

As a result I'd like to see in the report format of points of each client below me in the binary model tree. How can I design these tables to make my life easier in this kind of search ? I will always get my `soons` up to 9 levels down.

I know that with procedure I can solve this problem , however I would like to know an elegant and simple solution.

Thank you

Comment: Do some research on CTE's. What reporting tool are you using to represent this? SSRS? SSMS?

Comment: You may also wish to do dome research on the hierarchyid data type in SQL Server. This may or may not be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this using a with a recursive query:

```
with with_user_earns as (
    -- get father information (start)
    select father.id, father.str_name, father.id_father, father.ind_father_side_type, 1 as int_user_level from tb_user father where id = 9
    union all
    -- get all soons (stop condition)
    select son.id, son.str_name, son.id_father, son.ind_father_side_type, WUE.int_user_level + 1 from tb_user as son inner join with_user_earns as WUE on son.id_father = WUE.id where son.id_father is not null /*and WUE.int_user_level < 9*/
)

-- show result
select with_user_earns.id, with_user_earns.str_name, with_user_earns.id_father, with_user_earns.ind_father_side_type, with_user_earns.int_user_level from with_user_earns order by with_user_earns.int_user_level, with_user_earns.id
```